# Search by regex pattern with flipped subgroups

Tags: python

I want to find a pattern like `{xymyx}` in a string like:  `'9132123867'`

based on the pattern; the result should be: `'32123'`

I tried to do it with regex but I didn't know how to tell the pattern...

Can anyone do this with regex?
Or maybe you have a better idea!

Answer (score 6):

Swap captured groups within a regex pattern:

```
import re

s = '9132123867'
res = re.search(r'(\d)(\d)\d\2\1', s)
print(res.group())
```

---

```
32123
```

Comment: interesting technique! I didn't know about `\<NUMBER_OF_CAPTURE_GROUP>` till now!!!